# SQLITE/PHP on Raspberry Pi

Tags: web-server, mysql, php, sqlite

Wondering if this would be easy/possible. I know MySQL is commonly used but I want to make a sort of web server that can access the Raspberry Pi or more important an External Drive attached to it.

Basically my idea is to keep a library accessible via the web (I realize there are easier ways, but this would be a learning project for me).

Is this possible/easyish to do? Im guessing MySQL might be easier but ideally I need just one large table (maybe a few more later on. But right now it's just for movies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what stops you from issuing a simple:

```
sudo apt-get install php5 sqlite3 sqlite3-doc
```

works like a charm.

Comment: I figure you could, but would I be able to access an external drive with the database I suppose.

Comment: I have 1TB drive connected to my pi, works just fine. Haven't tried to put any databases there, but don't see any reason why this might not work.